# Remove duplicates, keep most recent record

Tags: sql

*Original post title:*  **query to delete duplicate values from a field 
    on the besis of maximum value in that column of a table 
    by keeping recent one**

---

I have a table named Idle_info: columns are

`open_date(date/time),time_from(date/time),duration(number),user(text)`

I want to delete the values if open_date and time_from is same. Only that value will be save where duration is maximum.

I tried this:

```
DELETE FROM Idle_info 
WHERE idle_duration NOT IN (SELECT MAX(i.idle_duration) 
FROM Idle_info i 
WHERE i.open_date = open_date AND i.time_from=time_from AND i.user=user 
GROUP BY i.open_date,i.time_from,i.idle_duration,i.user
```

but not working

thanks

Comment: *"but not working"* is very vague, do you get an error, is it running but not doing what you think it should? If you are getting an error, what is the message? What DBMS are you using?

Answer (score 1):

This is your query:

```
DELETE FROM Idle_info
     WHERE idle_duration NOT IN (SELECT MAX(i.idle_duration)
                                 FROM Idle_info i
                                 WHERE i.open_date = open_date AND i.time_from = time_from AND
                                       i.user = user
                                 GROUP BY i.open_date,i.time_from, i.idle_duration, i.user
                                )
```

My guess is that you want to keep the the most recent record for a given set of criteria.  You have two problems.  One is the lack of correlation.  The second is the `group by` clause.  I believe the following does what you want:

```
DELETE FROM Idle_info i
     WHERE i.idle_duration < (SELECT MAX(i.idle_duration)
                              FROM Idle_info i2
                              WHERE i.open_date = i2.open_date AND
                                    i.time_from = i2.time_from AND
                                    i.user = i2.user
                             );
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
DELETE FROM Idle_info r1
WHERE exists (select 1 
                  from idle_info r2 
                  where r1.user=r2.user 
                    and r1.time_from=r2.time_from 
                    and r1.open_date=r2.open_date
                    and r1.idle_duration<r2.idle_duration
              )
```